# Laravel, Livewire, @vite, add specific JS on the layout

Tags: javascript, laravel, vite, laravel-livewire

I'm learning Livewire, and I'm using Laravel with Vite and Bootstrap CSS.

Currently, my page is a full Livewire component, and its view is located at "*resources/views/livewire/adm/profile.blade.php*". I'm using a layout called "primal".

Here's the `render` function of my Livewire component:

```
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.adm.profile')
            ->extends('layouts.primal');
    }
```

This is my "primal" layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>

    </style>
    @vite(['resources/js/adm.js'])
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
    @livewireScripts  
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my "*adm.js*" file:

```
// Import our custom CSS - (bootstrap css)
import '../scss/adm.scss'

// Import all of Bootstrap's JS
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
window.bootstrap = bootstrap;

// profile page
const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')

const toastBootstrap = bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample)
window.addEventListener('notify', () => {
    toastBootstrap.show()
})
```

Currently, everything is working fine, and I can display a Toast message. However, I would like to be able to load the JavaScript that is specific to each component dynamically.

Currently, if I want to use my "primal" layout for another Livewire component, it will load the JavaScript for the "profile" page.

Is it possible to achieve something like this inside my layout, where I can change the value of "specific_js_for_the_component.js" dynamically?

```
@vite(['resources/js/adm.js','resources/js/specific_js_for_the_component.js'])
```

Or is there another option to achieve this?

Thank you for your help. Please excuse any mistakes in my English .

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have implemented a solution where I directly add the script inside my view component:

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="module">
        const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById('liveToast')

        const toastBootstrap = bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample)
        window.addEventListener('notify', () => {
            toastBootstrap.show()
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or alternative approaches. I'm open to exploring better and more elegant solutions.